# Sentiment analysis of tweets

Tags: pattern-matching, warning-messages, machine-learning

I want to use *Mathematica* for a sentiment analysis on tweet-messages. For that purpose i selected several tweets. Each tweet is interpreted by myself as positive (pos) of negative (neg). For example:

```
tweets = {{"Windows 10 why is It called windows 10 when there was no Windows 9?" , "neg"},
         {"Windows 10 so called because its an OS leap forward of many times or just because some coders got lazy?" , "neg"},
         {"did you hear why the new Windows is gonna be named Windows 10 no why because 7 ate 9", "pos"},
         {"i think everyone is excited with the upcoming Windows 10 release", "Pos"},
         {"Windows 10 Is a dirty gangsta that loves hoes", "neg"}}
```

To find a relation betweet the first string and de second I want to use de function Classify. Therefore I need to transforme the tweets.

```
tweets1 = (First@# -> Last@#) & /@ Transpose@{tweets[[1 ;;, 1]], tweets[[1 ;;, 2]]}
```

This gives the folowing output:

> {"Windows 10 Why Is It Called Windows 10 When There Was No Windows > 9?" -> "neg",   > > "Windows 10 so called because its an OS leap forward of many times or just because some coders got lazy?" -> "neg",
>   "Did you hear why the new Windows is gonna be named Windows 10 No,why Because 7 ate 9-> "pos",
>   "I think everyone is excited with the upcoming Windows 10 release" ->    "Pos", 
>   "Windows 10 Is a dirty gangsta that loves hoes" -> "neg"}

Then I use `Classify`:

```
c = Classify[tweets1]

c["Windows 10 is trending with more than 168 thousand tweet ! We wonder if it's a positive buzz or a negative one"]
```

gives 'neg'.

I think it's better to do a analysis on the separated words (or combination of words) of each tweet. Therefore I write:

```
tweets3 = (First@# -> Last@#) & /@ 
  Transpose@{StringCases[ToLowerCase[tweets2[[1 ;;, 1]]], 
     specials | RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]], 
    tweets2[[1 ;;, 2]]}
```

The output is:

> {{"windows", "why", "is", "it", "called", "windows", "when", "there", 
>   "was", "no", "windows"} ->    "neg", {"windows", "so", "called",
>   "because", "its", "an", "os",     "leap", "forward", "of", "many",
>   "times", "or", "just", "because",     "some", "coders", "got", "lazy"}
>   ->    "neg", {"did", "you", "hear", "why", "the", "new", "windows", "is",     "gonna", "be", "named", "windows", "no", "why", "because",
>   "ate"} ->    "pos", {"i", "think", "everyone", "is", "excited",
>   "with", "the",     "upcoming", "windows", "release"} ->    "Pos",
>   {"windows", "is", "a", "dirty", "gangsta", "that", "loves",
>   "hoes"} -> "neg"}

Then I use `Classify` again:

```
c = Classify[tweets3]
```

Now I get a error: 
Classify::bftlgth: Examples should have the same number of features.

Anyone a suggestion how to perform a sentiment analysis on twitter-messages?

Comment: `Transpose@{tweets[[1 ;;, 1]], tweets[[1 ;;, 2]]}` is the same as `tweets`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FYI a more elegant way to get `tweets1` is

```
tweets1 = Rule @@@ tweets;
```

`Classify` automatically separates words under the hood (via `StringSplit`), so you don't actually need to do that yourself.

`Classify` has a built in sentiment classifier:

```
Classify["Sentiment", "Windows 10 why is It called windows 10 when there was no Windows 9?"]

(* "Negative" *)
```

Comment: Thanks Chip. To add to this answer: we're working on discrete NLP functionality for 10.1, which should also unlock better performance from Classify when applied to textual data.